# Was Simon Gruber as ruthless as he made himself to be?

Tags: character, die-hard-with-a-vengeance

This movie was even more incredible than what I remembered. Everything just flowed perfectly and all the characters were on point.

Simon made it clear that he would never bomb a school full of children, but did he really believe McClane would be able to stop the bomb from vaporizing everyone in the train? I guess being willing to blow up a few people to further his goals would be looked at differently than targeting an entire school.

You could even see how reluctant one of his henchmen were at the idea of leaving a bomb out in the open for some kid to find. Simon seemed like he wanted to avoid as much collateral damage as possible outside of the subway bombing. It all just seems to go against the idea of bombing anything in general.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Movies & TV Stack Exchange! I believe you have two separate questions here that don't really relate to each other. If so, you may want to create a separate post for the second (Katya) Question (and edit the first one accordingly). For more on this Exchange Site's rules, please feel free to take a site tour: https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't want to clutter up the forums with multiple topics. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a forum. Please [**follow the tour**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @JayJohns That's ok, just take the site tour! Also don't be too disheartened if your first Q gets closed, as the community seems to think it will have primarily "opinion based" answers. Sometimes if you give the Q more focus, such as asking if an EP/Actor/Writer has shed any light on your Q, (ie: Did Jeremy Irons or Johnathon Hensliegh ever better explain Simon's behavior or is there anything in the screenplay/script) that can help keep the Q open and in theory there could be an interview out there somewhere...

Comment: It's an interesting question, but how could we objectively measure "how ruthless" the character is?